# Tensorflow, Keras : 'Model' object has not attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to run a video classification code with a CNN, however when training the model, I get this error :

File "C:\Users[my name]\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1532, in set_model
self.log_dir, self.model._get_distribution_strategy())  # pylint: disable=protected-access
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'

From what I understand, it's an error directly linked to the library keras. Do someone know if there is something to do to solve it or if there is a previous version of keras in which the 'model' object has an attribute '_get_distribution_strategy' ? I've seen this error in many similar codes I've tried to run these last days so I can't believe I'm the only one who have this issue.

Thanks for your help, everyone.

(Edit :

Here is the function train_model from which the error seems to come :

```
def train_model(model, nb_epoch, generators, callbacks=[]):
    train_generator, validation_generator = generators
    model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=100,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=10,
        epochs=nb_epoch,
        callbacks=callbacks)
    return model
```

and here are the imports made :

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard, EarlyStopping
```

)

Comment: can you add the code of the model especially the `import` you used to get needed libraries?

Comment: Sure, I just edited my post

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from using incompatible versions of `tensorflow` and `keras`. try to change all the imports from `from keras` to `from tensorflow.keras`

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard, EarlyStopping
```

If it doesn't work try to uninstall keras and use the same imports in the answer.